# No parse-exception in EnunciateJerseyServletContainer?

Tags: rest, jersey, jackson, enunciate

I have a rest-project which is using jersey+enunciate and now i wanna test the endpoints with malicious strings. The output of the programm seems to me like a JacksonParseException but with no details or stacktrace:

```
Unexpected character ('6' (code 54)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@28fe53cf; line: 1, column: 35]
```

I wanna catch the exception but even declaring an default error-page won't do the work, also the ExceptionMapper in jersey can't get it. (Seems to me it was catched before in the container and logged but not rethrown).

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a servlet filter that catches the exception.